# n-dimensional structure / map in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need a n-dimensional structure <s>(map)</s> in java.

Let's say we have an animal shop and we want to keep minimal prices for certain type of animal.

Let's say our criterias are:

- Type: Cat, Dog, ANY.
- Age: 1,2,ANY.
- Color: Brown, Red, ANY.
- Sex: Male,  Female, ANY.

Result price should be the lowest from all relating configurations.

For example min. price for

- Cat is 20,
- 1year-old is: 10,
- Brown cat: 25,
- Anything else: 30;

So the result price for brown, 1yold, dog, female is 10.

For black,  2yold, cat, male it's 20.
etc.

Are there any structures for that? If not, then what's the best way to implement one.

Comment: Have you tried just making a class? Not really clear what you're asking in relationship to the map.

Comment: I can't think of a data structure but have you thought of keeping a Hashmap and just keeping the minimum value that you get from each of the maps?

Comment: What does ANY mean in the criteria?

Comment: Most of your minimum price restrictions are based on a single criteria. But "brown cat" is a combination of two criteria, Type and Color. Do you want to be able to minimum prices for different combinations of criteria, or just for one criteria at a time?

Comment: @Andrew Janke: combinations, that's the problem.

Comment: @Patrick J Abare II: I'm trying to make a class, but i can't think of a good solution.

Comment: @Laszlo Lugosi: ANY means, you can specify a criterion that applies to any argument that will be passed for that dimension e.g cat, dog, pig, spider etc.

Comment: It's seems to me a dabatbase or big data problem. They can support you. Do you really need to solve this problem in JAVA?

Comment: @Laszlo Lugosi: solving this in java would be very preferable. Solving this as database problem seems quite easy, but i'd like to know java solution if there is any elegant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use just a Map or small set of Maps for this, since you want to define restrictions on combinations of multiple criteria. I don't see a way of determining an appropriate key to use, because you're not defining restrictions in terms of points in a multidimensional space, but in terms of possibly-overlapping spaces of various shapes. Your `ANY` is not functionally a distinct point on that dimension, but a range that covers all the other defined points, so you can't do simple equality comparisons for it, which is what Map keys need.

I would just keep all the restrictions in a `List` and check them all against your pet objects that you want to find the minimum price for. Make a `Restriction` class and give it an `appliesTo(Pet pet)` method.

If you ended up with a large set of restrictions, you could use Maps to build "indexes" on them if you introduced the notion of a "wildcard" to each of the criteria. You could then build map each of the values of each criteria, including a "wildcard" for all the conditions that could apply to pets with any value for that criteria, to a list of all the minimum price conditions that could possibly apply to that. This would be a lot more code, though, and probably wouldn't give you much speedup unless most of your restrict

Answer (score 2):

In my first attempt to answer this I missed the requirement that prices can be assigned to combinations of attributes. This answer should handle that part nicely.

Model each attribute in a way so that no two attributes have the same value. So for example if you have the dimensions eye color and fur color, don't just use Strings, because brown might belong to either of them. I assume the have a common interface 'Attribute' of no such interface exists you might use 'Object' instead. All such classes need to properly implement 'equals'

Now create a class to model combinations of attributes plus their price: (the following is written without IDE or compiler. Errors are to be considered intentional training for the reader)

```
public class AttributeCombination{
    private final Set<Attribute> attributes;

    public AttributeCombination(Set<Attribute> attributes){
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public boolean matches(Set<Attribute> attributes){
        for(a : this.attributes){
            if (!attributes.contains(a))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now have a properly ordered class combining Attributes with Prices

```
public class AttributeWithPrice implements Comparable<AttributeWithPrice> {
    private final AttributeCombination attributes;
    private final int price;

    // add the obvious constructor or switch to scala

    public int compareTo(AttributeWithPrice other){
        return this.price - other.price // or the other way round, I can never remember
    }
}
```

Now you can create a List of AttributeWithPrice objects, sort it, so the small prices come first, and iterate through it, until you find a matching element.

Comment: I guess that's ok if you include checking for ANY wildcard in matches(). Thanks.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to check for ANY explicitly, if you define the absence of a value for a particular type of criteria in the restriction means "applies to any". Think of it like an SQL `WHERE` clause: not mentioning a column means you're not filtering on it. A small tweak to the representation of criteria in the filters could make this easier: switch the `Set<Attribute>` to a `Map<AttributeType,List<Attribute>>`, where `AttributeType` is either a custom class, or a `String`, or `java.lang.Class`. No key for a criteria = unrestricted on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Map and a different class (possibly enum) for each "dimension".

The dimensions become the key for the map (key type must be the common super type, so probably Object) and the value type will be price (int judging from your examples).

To determine the price you pick the price based on each dimension and use the minimum of it. Done.

Comment: What about situation when you specify brown cat for 20 and the rest for 30? Using your solution for e.g. black cat you will get 20 instead of 30 because min for cat and black (any) will be 20.

Comment: Oh, I missed that one from your description ... will add another answer.